# Logistic regression with binomial independent variable

Tags: logistic, classification, binomial-distribution

I have a table of observations, with three columns --- (a) class labels (can be 0 or 1), (b) counts of successes (out of a certain number of Bernoulli trials) and, (c) numbers of Bernoulli trials. I would like to build a model to predict the class labels based on the (latter two) independent variables. Let us say the values in a row are $y$, $x$ and $n$. (Note that $n$ varies from row to row; $x$ is the number of success out of $n$ in the same row.)

If $\frac{x}{n}$ is high, the class label is more likely to be 1. I could use a logistic regression model to predict class labels based on $\frac{x}{n}$. However, the $n$ values vary a lot and when $n$ is small, I'd like for this to reflect in my predictions.

Can you please suggest how to do this properly? Explanations, with examples and sample R code will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

What it sounds like you want to do is use the proportion of successful trials AND the number of attempts in the logistic regression. What I would do, at least for starters, is create a variable that is the proportion $p$ of successes. Then do regression on both $n$ and $x/n$.

$$ logit(\hat{y}_i) = \beta_0 + \beta_1\dfrac{x_i}{n_i} + \beta_2n_i $$

The $\dfrac{x_i}{n_i}$ is the proportion of successes in row $i$. This will be a column in your data frame.